# How do I run VBA code on ListObject Change?

Tags: vba, excel

I know that I can write the following code in a sheets' VBA-object to run code on a worksheet change.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

Is there anything similar that I can write to run code whenever I filter a certain ListObject?

Answer (score 1):

Only in some cases.  Say we include a new column in the table that we fill with the value **1**.  Elsewhere we insert an

```
=SUBTOTAL()
```

formula to sum that column.  As the filter is operated the number of visible rows will vary.  The SUBTOTAL() function will re-calculate.

At this point a Calculate Event macro would catch the re-calculation!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

I added a ListBox Form Control to my Excel sheet..
[image]

Next, I assign a macro to this object by Right Clicking and choosing "Assign Macro".  (you may need to be in "Design Mode" to make this happen -- check the Developer Ribbon)

[image]

By default - the Macro Name is populated with a change event macro name.  Click "New" to create the macro.

[image]

Your macro is added to a Module.  Hope this helps!

[image]